# List of properties for fetch caught error

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Imagine you have this:

```
fetch('www.nonexistingwebpage.com', mySettings)
    .then(doTheThing);
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
        // returns "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
        // Or "TypeError: Failed to fetch"

    });
```

That's all well and good, but technically not something I can use. I would prefer to get more information out of the error object than just an error string so I can properly handle it.

After some searching, I found out one property of the `error` object is `message`, so I can do `error.message`. However, `error.type` and `error.status` are undefined. I'm looking for more information to use for handling and I can't seem to find it.

There seems to be absolutely 0 documentation about the options of the error object and I can't seem to find anything about it, so I was wondering if maybe anybody else knows exactly which properties I could call?

Comment: Generally, when the request fails with HTTP error, you should be able to inspect it using `type` and `status`. In your particular case, it might be that `mySettings` is setting the desired response type to JSON and the response fails JSON deserialization. Check your raw response data to examine further.

Comment: Everything you need or want to know about the `Fetch` Standard: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: try `console.log({error});` ( notice the added brackets )

Comment: @Taki thank you, that really cleared things up! It apparently only has `.message` and `.stack` haha.

Comment: "Everything you need or want to know about the Fetch Standard fetch.spec.whatwg.org" that is a lot to parse through to find what errors you need to handle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you catch an Error, typically it is an Error object (usually called an Exception in most languages).

The best way to handle specific exceptions is not through its properties, but through its type. For example, you got a Syntax error and you can check this with:

```
if (err instanceof SyntaxError) {
   // Do something specifically for syntax errors
}
```

Comment: I had not thought about it like this. This will allow me to create very elegant solutions, I thank you for it.